# Updating SandForce SSD on JMicron controller in AHCI mode

Tags: ssd, raid, firmware, pata, ahci

I would like to update my A-Data S599 drive using ASUS P5V-VM DH board. The board have 2 controllers one is VIA and the other is JMicron. Only JMicron supports AHCI mode which is required to update firmware, but the updater doesn't see it (I've got a NFTS partition and I booting from other drive).

When running from VIA controller the drive is being shown, updates properly, but firmware remains the same after reboot so it failes silenty.

There are only two modes IDE/RAID on this controller.

A-data support is not responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMicron/nVidia/ATI/Marvell/VIA controllers are not supported. Only Intel in AHCI mode is supported.